# SQL Query to roll down the manager hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

The scenario is :-
Joyce is a MGR, reporting to Pam. Greg is a MGR reporting to Joyce, thus rolling up to Pam.

So for a very high level person,you will see all the reportees directly or indirectly related to him with the query.

Table with the information TABLE_MGR :-

```
Employee    MGR

Joyce       PAM
GREG        JOYCE
```

So the desired output will be as

```
 Employee    MGR

Joyce       PAM
GREG        PAM
```

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you've written and the output your code produces, or the errors you're seeing. Thanks.

Comment: I think he wants to see in a hierarchy the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `connect by` clause together with `connect_by_root`.

Have a look into the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm).

Example

```
create table tmp_emp as  
 select 'JOYCE' employee, 'PAM' mgr from dual
 union
 select 'GREG' employee, 'JOYCE' mgr from dual;

select level, CONNECT_BY_root mgr root_mgr, t.*
from tmp_emp t
start with mgr = 'PAM'
connect by nocycle prior employee = mgr;
```

Output

```
     LEVEL ROOT_MGR EMPLOYEE MGR  
---------- -------- -------- -----
         1 PAM      JOYCE    PAM  
         2 PAM      GREG     JOYCE

2 rows selected.
```

**Edit:**

There is no need to use the `start with`. This will also work

```
select level, CONNECT_BY_root mgr root_mgr, t.*
from tmp_emp t
connect by nocycle prior employee = mgr;
```

But maybe you only want the employees with no manager you could do this. It also shows you the hierarchy to the top manager.

```
with roots as 
(
   select level lvl, CONNECT_BY_root mgr root_mgr, employee,  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(mgr, '/') "Path"
   from tmp_emp t
   connect by  prior employee = mgr
)
select * 
from roots r1 
where root_mgr not in (select employee from roots r2 );
```

Output

```
       LVL ROOT_MGR EMPLOYEE Path          
---------- -------- -------- -------------
         2 PAM      GREG     /PAM/JOYCE
         1 PAM      JOYCE    /PAM
```

Comment: Hi @hol This is correct but i dont know the top manager and there are 1000 rows like these with employee and manager relationship... i cannot use start with !

Comment: I made an edit. I saw you also made an edit to your question. I think it still gives you the result you want. I exclude all the employees that have no manager on there own. But your data model may works a bit different and you want to use a START WITH MANAGER_FLAG='Y'